# ROS Answers SE migration: Qt Multimedia

Tags: ros, pyqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot seem to import QtMultimedia widgets and other items into my python script with the following line:

from python_qt_binding.QtMultimedia import *

is QtMultimedia not included in the python_qt_bindings?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255668/qt-multimedia/) by [inkspell4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28072/inkspell4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it's listed, but it's optional: https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/blob/kinetic-devel/src/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py#L69 . I've tried `import PyQt4.QtMultimedia` but it doesn't work either, so I suspect this is actually QtMultimedia missing from PyQt4

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1